# Does the Latest Ubuntu Download (.iso file) contain latest fixes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, updates, ubuntu-11.04

If I go to [the website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) and download the ISO file is it the exact same one that was released in April or will it contain the latest patches (e.g. security fixes, etc) that have been release since then?

If it doesn't I suppose I'll have to download the entire ISO file, install the OS, and then have another couple hundred MB to download which is not what I'd prefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It only contains up to that release point.

Any additional updates to the software contained within the distribution will be updated after you complete the installation.

What you are looking for is a distro that does rolling releases.  Check out this question over at [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740/what-distributions-have-rolling-releases) it's from 2010 but scanning through it, it's still fairly relevant.

Comment: I don't think a rolling release is really what he's looking for. Even Arch Linux doesn't include the newest patches in the ISO (because it would mean rebuilding a new ISO every couple hours).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but at the same time a rolling release will also have a much smaller list of updates to run after the initial installation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm **not** 100% sure on this one and don't have time to test it in a VM, however my educated guess would be that no, there are no fixes in the image.

Integrating fixes into the .iso would require nightly builds compiled into image files and that just doesn't seem very efficient when you can get them via one large update. Also, seeing as some fixes are hardware/environment dependent, including them in an image wouldn't make much sense (unless there were .iso images created for every type of hardware Ubuntu can run on).

Once you installed just `sudo apt-get update` and wait around for a while :)